# Why can't I add a border on my svg path?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a `svg` where I am highlighting my `path` on `hover`.  Here is my `svg`

```
<svg version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 2986 886" enable-background="new 0 0 2986 886">
  <image display="block" overflow="visible" width="2986" height="886" xlink:href="/A-1.jpg">
  </image>
  <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" strokeWidth="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="2781.5,905 2986,905 2986,865.6
    2842.7,634.6 2635.2,601.1 " id="1"></path>
   ....
</svg>
```

Here is my `css`:

```
svg path{
  fill:none;
  pointer-events:all;
}

svg path:hover {
    fill:  rgba(73,143,226,0.80);
    border: 5px solid #31C6FF;
}

svg rect:hover {
    fill:  rgba(73,143,226,0.80);
    border: 5px solid #31C6FF;
}

svg polygon:hover {
    fill:  rgba(73,143,226,0.80);
    border: 5px solid #31C6FF;
}
```

When I `hover`, my `path` changes to the proper color, but I don't get a `border`.  What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `SVG`, use the `stroke` property instead of `border`.

Edit: As the owner of the question points out in comments, `stroke-opacity: 1` was needed as well as `stroke` and `stroke-width`.

Comment: I changed it to `stroke` and added a `stroke-width: 5px` and still nothing happened.

Comment: I changed it to `stroke`, added a `stroke-width` and `stroke-opacity: 1` and it worked.

Comment: Not sure what you both are talking about here. `stroke-opacity: 1` should not have been needed.  It defaults to `1` and you weren't changing that anywhere. There were a bunch of other problems with the above SVG: OP had `<path>` when it should have been `<polygon>`; used `border` when they should have used `stroke`; used `strokeWidth` instead of `stroke-width` and had a extremely tiny value of stroke width compared to the size of the viewBox. If you fix all those, things work just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/eh6hmguw/